# Syntax of Manipulate in combination with Locator in Mathematica

Tags: syntax, wolfram-mathematica

I have difficulties understanding the syntax of the following expression:

```
Manipulate[  Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, p}], PlotRange -> 2], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

According to the [documentation of Manipulate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html) the syntax looks like this:

```
Manipulate[expr, {u, u_min, u_max}]
Manipulate[expr, {u, u_min, u_max, du}]
Manipulate[expr, {{u, u_init}, u_min, u_max, ...}]
Manipulate[expr, {{u, u_init, u_lbl}, u_min, u_max, ...}]
Manipulate[expr, {u, {u_1, u_2,...}}]
```

[Locator](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Locator.html) should work like this:

```
Locator[{x, y}]
Locator[Dynamic[pos]]
Locator[{x, y}, obj]
Locator[{x, y}, None]
```

I assume `{{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}` maps to `Manipulate[expr, {{u, u_init}, ...}]`
where `u_init` is `{1, 1}` but then there is a parameterless `Locator` where I 
would expect a minimum value.

What role plays the Locator in the above syntax descriptions?

Comment: @skaffman: Thanks, don't know how I could get the mathematica tag wrong.

Comment: Documentation Center > Manipulate > More Information. Second bullet item describes this notation. See both 4th and 11th subitems.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks, I must be blind. I went through all the links at the end but I never saw the "More Information". All the other functions make a lot more sense now too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation for `Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html) states (in the "More information" box):

> ```
>  {u,Locator}          a locator in a graphic
> ```
>
> In the form {u, Locator}, the value of u is a list giving x and y coordinates. The coordinates refer either to the first graphic in expr, or range from 0 to 1 in each direction across expr.
>
> The form {{u, {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ...}}, Locator} sets up a locator for each of the `{xi, yi}`, and makes the value of u be the list of all.
>
> The option setting LocatorAutoCreate specifies that new locators should be added for clicks that do not hit existing locators. Alt+Click deletes locators.
>
> {{u, {}}, Locator, LocatorAutoCreate->All} starts with no locators, but allows locators to be created.